# Xamarin.Forms with Realm - issue resolving files when bulding iOs

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, realm

I've created a Xamarin.Forms solution (with PCL) and included realm nuget both on all my pcl's and my platform specific projects. When I compile the iOS project from within Visual Studio 2015 (from a PC connected to my mac)

I get following compile error:

```
:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(700,3): error : 
Failed to resolve assembly: 'Realm.Sync, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null''
```

But from my mac running in Xamarin Studio, it compiles without any problem.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Looking into this, comparing something built from scratch on Mac, in case anyone thinks it is neglected ;-)

Comment: Having the same issue with native (Xamarin.iOS).

Comment: Please try building with the 1.0.4 NuGet - see the breaking change in https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md that was added in 1.1.0

Comment: I tried, but that didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: As just communicated in email - try removing Realm, cleaning bin and obj folders then add the Realm nugets back selecting 1.0.4. Getting the (new) 1.1.0 version out of the build may be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by Andy Dent actually solved the problem - we had later crash, which lead me to think it didn't, but that was on our side.

Please try building with the 1.0.4 NuGet - see the breaking change in github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md that was added in 1.1.0

Comment: 1.1.1 was released that should fix the issue. Please try it out and let us know if you still experience problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the Realm issue [1264](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1264) to track this but will copy solutions here.